# Change Menu Item's links Dynamically, per page basis

Tags: 7

I've been looking for this for a while, but found no solution.

What I want is: Whenever someone visits to a user's profile, say http://mysite.com/user/**1** there should be an *item* available in ***Main Menu***, with the link: http://mysite.com/custom_module/**1**

Here, I'll be dynamically changing the menu item's links based on the current page. How to achieve that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how exactly you want to change the links, but [views](http://drupal.org/project/views) can handle most links if you configure the contextual filters correctly.  Basically, just display a link to the content as the field and then set your filters and contextual filters (getting the argument from the node/user) as you need.

If you just want to change around links for user profiles, there's also the [me](http://drupal.org/project/me) module.

Comment: Hi Patrick,

Thanks for reply. I can use it with Views and templates, but the client wants it done using Menus.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  You can use views to generate a menu.  Is it a configuration issue?  You can always set up a simple admin view to allow your client to make the edits more easily.